# It is acceptable to say 'Good night, sir. Have you reserved a table?'

Tags: word-usage

While I was flicking through English Vocabulary In Use, I came across this sentence
'Good night, sir. Have you reserved a table?'

To my knowledge,'Good night' expresses good wishes on parting at night or before going to bed.

Is this usage of 'Good night' acceptable in this context?

Comment: Technically it's OK, but yes, the meaning has overwhelmingly become a kind of goodbye. Better to say "Good evening, sir …"

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you supply the author's name, and the book's  level? I might have a copy of it at home, somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth an answer, but I can confirm it's a perfectly normal greeting in Guyana (as indicated in my comment on the answer below). I know this only from personal experience.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: *[What is an appropriate greeting to use at night time?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100870)* and *[“Good night” or “good evening”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13142)*

Answer (score 4):

OED does indicate that “Good night” **can** be used as a greeting, but it’s unusual (and certainly in BrE, it would be unusual to the point of downright oddity):

> 1. a. Expressing good wishes on parting (or occas. meeting) at night or before going to bed.

OED’s earliest citation for this meaning is from around 1496. It’s not obvious that any of its citations show usage on meeting, though.

> 2. Chiefly *Caribbean.* Expressing good wishes on meeting during the evening. = **Good evening** *int.*

OED has citations from 1844 to 2009 for this usage as a greeting meaning “Good evening.” They have found evidence for it, as you have; but finding evidence is no indication of how general the usage is, in the Caribbean region or elsewhere.

Comment: Bidding someone *good night* as a greeting would be equally odd here. It would confuse people.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of having heard *goodnight* used as a greeting in Ireland, but I can't find any Irish reference in the OED. It would be interesting to know if anyone else recognises it as Irish.

Comment: It is in general usage in Guyana. "Good night" is a greeting used at night, including when answering the phone.

Answer (score 0):

"Good evening, sir. Do you have a reservation?" is acceptable.

Saying "Good night, sir. Have you reserved a table?" is a lot like saying "Bonne nuit, monsieur. Avez-vous une réservation?"