# "Vendors and consultants, each of which" or "... each of whom"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

Which is correct:

> - Sources of information include vendors and consultants, each of which usually has an interest in selling something.
> - Sources of information include vendors and consultants, each of whom usually have an interest in selling something.

Comment: "each of whom usually ***has***" - 'each' is singular.

Comment: also related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105794/i-dont-know-which-boy/105797#105797 The two answers explain the usage of who/whom vs which, very well.

Answer (score 2):

Are they people or companies? People take *whom* and things take *which*. Companies are things, not people (despite the statement of politicians and legal analysis to the contrary).

If, when talking about your vendors and consultants you are clearly referring to individuals, use *whom*. Otherwise *which*.

And as suggest in the comment, use *has* since *each* is singular.