# Is it correct to have 'a' before a proper noun?

Tags: proper-nouns, indefinite-articles

According to my knowledge, the indefinite article 'a' must never be used before a proper noun. But I recently heard the English sentence: "Every civilian should be a Mahatma Gandhi to his society".

As per my knowledge, "Mahatma Gandhi" is a proper noun here and 'a' is the article.

Believing the speaker to have a good grasp of English, I now have this doubt: are there any occasions where it is proper to have an indefinite article before a proper noun?

Please advise me.

Comment: (1) Don't you mean 'According to my knowledge, the article 'a' must **not** be used before a proper noun'? (2) The word 'English' is a proper adjective here. It's capitalised in most registers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Edwin Ashworth for correcting my question. Please also correct if you find any errors in this comment.

Comment: Used in that context can Mahatma Gandhi be said to be a 'proper noun'?

Comment: Be aware that *as per my knowledge* isn’t real English. See also
[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/256),
[2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6473),
[3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20525).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'rule' is as usual better termed a 'guideline'.

There are not uncommon occasions when there is not the usual definiteness attaching to the referent (actual thing being named by) a proper noun. Thus:

> There's a London in Canada and eight Londons in the US.
>
> There's a Jack Robinson who lives on our street.
>
> We've just bought a Dyson.

As Jasper indicates, this includes metaphorical usages (which 'Dyson' arguably still is):

> He's never going to be a Denis Law / He's no Denis Law.

Comment: Not to mention "the question was asked by one Shashikanth Komandor" which is sometimes "a Shashikanth".

Comment: Thanks Edwin Ashworth for giving me the answer. I got a good clarity over the usage of the articles in these occassions.

Answer (score 2):

*Mahatma Ghandi* here refers to a person with his qualities. It does not literally mean Mahatma Ghandhi himself. In this case, the use of *a* is correct. Another example:

> We cannot expect everyone to be a Gautama Buddha or a Jesus Christ.

Comment: Yes. Capital loss accompanies genericisation (google; hoover) but can be disrespectful, especially to real persons.

Comment: Thanks Jasper Loy for your reply. I am satisfied with the answer.