# Is "Via our phone conversation earlier" correct in business email writing?

Tags: word-usage

I saw my colleague wrote "Via our phone conversation earlier,...." in the email and was wondering if it is grammatically correct. And, What is the professional way to email someone to confirm the agreement after talking on the phone?

I come up with other ways to say but seems a bit diffuse.

1.After talking with you on the phone,...
2.According to our discussion via phone,...
3....

Can anyone teach me and give me more examples? 
Thanks.

Comment: He probably meant *per*, but *via our phone conversation earlier* could be perfectly fine, grammatical, and idiomatic, depending on what he meant: "*You communicated to me, via our phone conversation earlier, that*...". See? Perfectly fine. A bit stilted, but so is *per*, and since you're asking for "formal business speak", I imagine you're actually aiming for stilted.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [**as per**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-per-instructions) ( eg *"as per our conversation this morning"*):

> Formal: according to instruction or agreement

(but the 'as' is strictly redundant, and see [What is the difference between "as per" and "according to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256/what-is-the-difference-between-as-per-and-according-to))

Answer (score 1):

Based on the context, it looks like 'per' was intended.

In this case, the implied meaning is *'in reference to* our phone conversation earlier'.

If this was the intent then 'per' would be the correct usage.

Comment: I agree. But in a slightly different instance such as the one @Dan Bron uses in his comment ( 'This was communicated *via* my phone call yesterday') then *via* seems to fit better.