# To browse a shop or to browse in a shop

Tags: meaning, prepositions

One *browses* magazines and the Internet, or one can *browse through* them. Any dictionary will say as much.

On the same token one can *browse through* a shop.

However, an N-gram proves that you will more often *browse in* a shop rather than simply *browse* a shop. Why is that? Is there a change in meaning? After all, whether it's a magazine, the Internet or a shop, I'm still glancing at stuff (whether reading or looking at images/objects).

Comment: You could add research from say [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/browse) (which has the 'browse a shop' example). It happily lists both transitive and intransitive usages.

Comment: The difference is that a shop is a place, so you can be *in* it. And browsing the products is something you do while you're in there.

Comment: From "browse the shop" I would take away the meaning that one looked through the window, to decide if it was worth entering. From "browse in the shop" I would take away the meaning that the person was in the shop, to decide if any products were worth purchasing.

Comment: @Davo: that really answered my question. Would you like to put it in an answer?

Comment: Similar to many other shortenings in context, e.g _shop (at/in) the mall_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **browse the shop**, I would take away the meaning that one looked through the window, to decide if it was worth entering.

From **browse in the shop**, I would take away the meaning that the person was in the shop, to decide if any products were worth purchasing.

Comment: 8 out of the first 10 Google hits I've found for "browsed the shop" demand that the usage is merely a variant of "We browsed in/round the shop", and the other two probably mean the same. This is as I'd expect the expressions to be used.

Answer (score 2):

**Browse the shop**

Checkout the shop, investigate the shop, thorough look at the shop.*

**Browse in the shop**

Checkout the products in the shop, investigate the products in the shop, thorough look at the products in the shop.*

*As per my knowledge

Comment: Note that "as per my knowledge* really isn’t English. See also
[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/256),
[2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6473),
[3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20525).