# Third Conditional "even if I had got"

Tags: meaning-in-context, conditionals

What does the sentence below imply?

> "I wouldn't have studied even if I had got the book."

As per my knowledge, implication should be – I wouldn't study regardless of condition; the first phrase is independent of the second phrase, no matter the condition, the action of studying wouldn't be done.

Comment: In context, it's reasonable to assume it's something like this. "I know you didn't study because you didn't get the book." "Actually, I wouldn't have studied even if I **had** got the book." Although the lack of the book prevented the studying, it wasn't the *only* thing that prevented it.

Comment: The "even if.." phrase serves as an intensifier. "I would not have studied even under the ideal condition of having obtained the book that would have facilitated my study."

Comment: Please be aware that *as per my knowledge* isn’t “real English”. For details please see the answers to such questions as
[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/256),
[2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6473),
[3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20525).