# What should I use instead of "From my Knowledge"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I'm trying to find a word for a summary about bullying, and speaking up . Since I know how it feels, what should I use instead of "From my Knowledge"

According to the article ”Stomp out bullying!” by Jennifer Dignan they state,

> Some students don't report bullying because the dont want to be labeled a “tattler”*...Talking from my knowledge...*

Comment: Speaking from experience

Comment: You can use quotations (`>` before a paragraph) to separate the text to be considered from the background for the question. Also, save the elaboration for the question body, keeping the title short and searchable.

Comment: Please be warned that *from my knowledge* to mean *as far as I know* is ***ɴᴏᴛ* a native-speaker collocation in English.** It sounds quite strange to us; we would no more say or write it in almost any circumstance conceivable than we would the even more alien *(as) per my knowledge* collocation that certain subcontinental learners of English from incorrectly seem mysteriously drawn to using.  Please see also [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/256), [2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6473), [3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20525).

Comment: @tchrist Can you explain? We use "AFAIK" as shorthand for this phrase in text messages often.

Comment: @Steve It's "From my knowledge" that native speakers do not use.

Answer (score 2):

'Based on my personal experience' yields both an in-depth air while keeping a humble tone.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions I have are:
"From my experience" or "In my experience..."
If the summary is informal, you can say something along the lines of 'trust me, I'd know.' or 'from past experiences/events.'
However, if this is a summary, I don't think you should be putting your opinions in at all. But I don't know what context you're writing in, so never mind.

Comment: Hello, Ivy. You can ask the poster for more context with a comment under their question.